# How show Text as placeholder for bootstrap date picker

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, datepicker, react-bootstrap, bootstrap-5

How can you show text instead of a date as a placeholder for a Form Control?

```
          <Form.Control
            type="date"
            placeholder="Select date"
          />
```

Which results in:
[image: Form control date]

Expected result:
[image: Expected result date]

Im using:
https://react-bootstrap.github.io/forms/form-control/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import Container from "react-bootstrap/Container";
import Form from "react-bootstrap/Form";
import "./App.css";

const App = () => {
  const [inputType, setInputType] = useState("text");

  return (
    <Container className="p-3">
      <Form>
        <Form.Control
          type={inputType}
          placeholder="Select date"
          onFocus={() => setInputType("date")}
          onBlur={() => setInputType("text")}
        />
      </Form>
    </Container>
  );
};

export default App;
```

https://codesandbox.io/s/react-bootstrap-input-type-date-placeholder-st87v0?file=/src/App.js